# Webpack build not working on older browsers

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I'm using webpack and my app works locally and in production but it doesn't work on older devices (Ex. iPad running iOS 12.5). The HTML loads and everything is in the  tags but the body is empty. I also get an error in the console when it loads.
[image]
[image]

I suspect that this is because I am not supporting older browsers so I added coverage in my package.json with the browserslist key (cover 99%). I also added a bable.config.js file but it didn't change anything.

```html
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "vitest run --coverage --reporter verbose",
    "build": "npx webpack --mode production",
    "build:dev": "npm run build --silent -- --env dbmode=development",
    "build:prod": "npm run build --silent -- --env dbmode=production",
    "start": "npx webpack serve --open --mode development",
    "start:dev": "npm run start --silent -- --env dbmode=development",
    "start:prod": "npm run start --silent -- --env dbmode=production"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "cover 96%"
  ],
  "homepage": "https://github.com/Zio-4/my-roar-app",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.0",
    "@bdelab/roar-firekit": "^1.2.0",
    "@jspsych/plugin-audio-keyboard-response": "^1.1.2",
    "@jspsych/plugin-fullscreen": "^1.1.2",
    "@jspsych/plugin-html-button-response": "^1.1.2",
    "@jspsych/plugin-html-keyboard-response": "^1.1.2",
    "@jspsych/plugin-preload": "^1.1.2",
    "@jspsych/plugin-survey-text": "^1.1.2",
    "@jspsych/plugin-video-button-response": "^1.1.2",
    "@jspsych/plugin-video-keyboard-response": "^1.1.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "firebase": "^9.17.2",
    "jspsych": "^7.3.1",
    "papaparse": "^5.4.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.11",
    "roarr": "^7.14.3",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.21.4",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^9.2.0",
    "@vitest/coverage-c8": "^0.30.1",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.3",
    "eslint": "^8.35.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
    "folder-hash": "^4.0.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "jsdom": "^21.1.1",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0"
  }
}
```

babel.config.js

```html
const presets = [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        targets: "cover 99%",
        useBuiltIns: "usage",
        corejs: "3.6.4",
      },
    ],
  ];
  
  module.exports = { presets };
```

webpack.config.js

```html
* eslint-disable quote-props */
const { hashElement } = require('folder-hash');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const commonConfig = {
  entry: {
    index: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'index.js'),
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].[contenthash].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    clean: {
      keep: /\.git/,
    },
  },
  optimization: {
    moduleIds: 'deterministic',
    runtimeChunk: 'single',
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name(module) {
            // get the name. E.g. node_modules/packageName/not/this/part.js
            // or node_modules/packageName
            const packageName = module.context.match(/[\\/]node_modules[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/)[1];

            // npm package names are URL-safe, but some servers don't like @ symbols
            return `npm.${packageName.replace('@', '')}`;
          },
          chunks: 'all',
        },
      },
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          filename: 'img/[name][ext]',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.mp3$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: 'audio',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.mp4$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: 'video',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.csv$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: 'csv',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  experiments: {
    topLevelAwait: true,
  },
};

const productionConfig = {
  mode: 'production',
};

const developmentConfig = {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    static: './dist',
  },
};

module.exports = async (env, args) => {
  const hashOptions = {
    folders: { exclude: ['.*', 'node_modules', 'test_coverage'] },
    files: { include: ['*.js', '*.json'] },
  };
  const srcHash = await hashElement('./src', hashOptions);

  const roarDbDoc = env.dbmode === 'production' ? 'production' : 'development';

  let merged;
  switch (args.mode) {
    case 'development':
      merged = merge(commonConfig, developmentConfig);
      break;
    case 'production':
      merged = merge(commonConfig, productionConfig);
      break;
    default:
      throw new Error('No matching configuration was found!');
  }

  return merge(merged, {
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ title: 'My Roar App' }),
      new webpack.ids.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(), // so that file hashes don't change unexpectedly
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        ROAR_DB_DOC: JSON.stringify(roarDbDoc),
        SRC_HASH: JSON.stringify(srcHash),
      }),
    ],
  });
};
```

Any idea on what I need to do to make it work on older browsers?